# Check whether facebook user likes my app

Tags: vb.net, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I've read several sources now but did not find a solution: I'm using [Facebook C# SDK](http://csharpsdk.org/) with ASP.net 4 and VB.net 2010. I have a Facebook Canvas application. I'm using Canvas Auth.Authorize and it works fine. Now I want to know whether the currently logged in user already likes my app. How could I do that?

- 'SignedRequest' does not seem to work because according to [Facebook Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) "This field is only present if your app is being loaded within a Page Tab".
- graph/user/likes is also not an option because I don't want to ask the user to grant access for my app to all his likes.

But the Facebook Plugin is able to differ whether the current user likes my app or not, so I'm quite optimistic that there is a way which I just did not find yet.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the graph API to call the users likes. Instead of requesting all of the likes simply request the single one you want.

https://graph.facebook.com/userId/likes/appId

If you the user has liked the page the result will return details about the page. For example:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "Microsoft Office Web Apps", 
      "category": "Software", 
      "id": "121883824529155", 
      "created_time": "2012-03-14T06:48:47+0000"
    }
  ], 
  "paging": {
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes/121883824529155?format=json&limit=5000&offset=5000&__after_id=121883824529155"
  }
}
```

If the user has not liked the page you will receive empty data.

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

With the Facebook C# SDK you would make this request as follows:

```
var client = FacebookClient("access_token_here");
dynamic result = client.Get('/me/appId');
if (result.data.Length == 1) {
  // User has liked page
}
```

Comment: Hi Nathan, thanks for your reply! It works as expected but 2 comments: 1. yor last code examples misses the '/likes' in the URL. 2. I don't understand how the LIKE is connected to my app? I have e.g. an app 'MyApp' (apps.facebook.com/myapp), a corresponding page (www.facebook.com/MyApp) and a domain name (myapp.com). The LIKE is not corresponding to any of these. Instead I could only see it with the connect-url supplied in http://misha.beshkin.lv/how-to-add-like-box-to-your-app-on-facebook/ but there I get only the question mark as app icon etc. So to which url does the LIKE belong to?

Comment: OK, found it. In the /me/likes/appId I don't use the AppID but the PageID and this works fine!